# C array initialization error when size is larger than 2.1 million

Tags: arrays, c, gdb

I am new to C and I wrote a simple program to find prime numbers. However, when I use an n value larger than ~2.1 million, the program stops working on line 25 at `bool arr[n+1];`. I used gdb debuger and this is the exception message:

___chkstk_ms (Unknown Source:0)
[Unknown/Just-In-Time compiled code] (Unknown Source:0).

For some reason, when I made n=2,075,000 I got this error instead:

msvcrt.dll!msvcrt!_setjmpex (Unknown Source:0)

Otherwise it works fine for lower values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{   
    printf("Up to which number do you need to count how many prime numbers there are? ");
    int n;
    scanf("%i", &n);
    getchar();
    if (n<0) 
    {
        printf("Wrong input kind. Only natural numbers are accepted. \n");
        return -1;
    }
    else if (n<2)
    {
        printf("There are 0 prime numbers");
        return 0;
    }
    

    // Initialize an array representing all number up to including n. 
    //  0 and 1 are not prime, init the others as being prime
    bool arr[n+1];
    arr[0] = arr[1] = false;

    for (int i = 2; i<=n; i++) arr[i] = true;

    for (int i = 2; i<=sqrt(n); i++)
    {   
        if (arr[i]) //if prime number
        {   
            for (int k = i*i; k<=n; k+=i) //set its multiples as non-prime
            {
                arr[k] = false;
            }
        }
    }


    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i<=n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i]) count++;
    }
    
    printf("In total, there are %i prime numbers up to %i\n", count, n);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local variables are typically created on the stack which has a limited amount of space.  Over 2 million elements in an array will overflow the stack in most cases causing your program to crash.

Use `malloc` instead to create the memory on the heap which has a much higher limit.

```
bool *arr = malloc(sizeof(bool) * (n+1));
```

Comment: And of course, use `free(arr)` when you're done with it then.